# How to attach information to a class hierarchy?

Tags: c++

Assume I have a class hierarchy in a lower level

```
class A {...};
class A0 : public A {...};
class A1 : public A {...};
class A2 : public A {...};
```

And I want to represent it in a higher level like a GUI level with icons, it may be easy to add a virtual method in those classes

```
virtual Icon A::icon() {return iconOfA;}
virtual Icon A0::icon() {return iconOfA0;}
virtual Icon A1::icon() {return iconOfA1;}
virtual Icon A2::icon() {return iconOfA2;}
```

However, I don't want to change the low level classes, any simple way to implement it? I hope to use it dynamically, like

```
A* a = new A2();
getIcon(a); // will return iconOfA2.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Declare `icon` as a virtual function in the base class A. And geticon takes the base class pointer or reference and calls the icon on that base class variable.

Comment: That is want I don't want as shown in my question.

Comment: this require to overrirde icon() in derived classes what OP wants to avoid

Comment: all I can think of from seeing this question is to use polymorphism. by defining an abstract class with virtual function, you can derive new class with different definition of that function... similar to what you have done in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Icon getIcon(A* a_ptr){
    A0* a0_ptr = dynamic_cast<A0*>(a_ptr);
    if(a0_ptr){
        return iconOfA0;
    }
    A1* a1_ptr = dynamic_cast<A1*>(a_ptr);
    if(a1_ptr){
        return iconOfA1;
    }
    A2* a2_ptr = dynamic_cast<A2*>(a_ptr);
    if(a2_ptr){
        return iconOfA2;
    }
    return Icon();
}
```

alternatively declare a map:

```
typedef std::map<const type_info*, Icon> Iconmap;
Iconmap iconmap;

//...
iconmap.insert(std::make_pair(&typeid(A0), Icon()));
iconmap.insert(std::make_pair(&typeid(A1), Icon()));
iconmap.insert(std::make_pair(&typeid(A2), Icon()));
//...
```

and return icon based on RTTI:

```
Icon getIcon(A* ptr){
    Iconmap::iterator it = iconmap.find(&typeid(*ptr));
    if(it!=iconmap.end()){
        return (*it).second();
    }else{
        return Icon();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a map at GUI level that will have class for key and icon for value.  Icon belongs to GUI, and it probably has nothing to do with class itself.

Comment: +1 - separation of concerns is a very important, and frequently overlooked - concept

Comment: How to implement it, especially for having class for key?

Comment: Either define `classname` at some upper level in the hierarchy or use rtti.

Answer (score 1):

use RTTI:

```
if (typeid(*a).name()==typeid(A0).name()) return iconOfA0; else if
(typeid(......
```

Comment: This works but may be hard to maintain compared with the easy polymorphic way. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have an Icon data field in the base class A.  This should be public or protected so that it is accessible in the derived classes.  Then the constructor for each of classes could set the value to their own version of the icon.  The getIcon method will always return the right kind of Icon for the glass and the method need only be defined in the base class.